# Pandas resampling (daily to monthly time series) to get first available value every month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` consisting of 2 columns: `DATE` and `DTB6` (yield on a 6-month T-bill). The data frequency is daily, and I want it converted to monthly. I want to take the first value out of every month, or the following day until you find a non-missing value on the `DTB6` column.

For example, for the month of May, May 1st doesn't have a quoted yield, but May 2nd does. Can I use the resampling function to get it to find the available value closest to the beginning of the month?

This is what I have so far:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('DTB6.csv')
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df = df.set_index('DATE')
```

This is to set `DATE` as a datetime index, because it was a string originally. Then I do `bymonthly = df.resample('MS').first()`, but this doesn't work for the 1st of every month. I tried dropping rows with missing values, but it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could explore using an agg function after your resample to keep the first value, modifying the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938392/5699807)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `agg` function:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("DTB6.csv")
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])

result = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="MS", key="DATE")).agg(
    first_yield=("DTB6", "first"),
    mean_yield=("DTB6", "mean"),
)
```

Comment: I tried that code but it gave me an error on pd.Grouper() because of on="DATE". It said it expected 'axis'. Sorry if this is trivial, I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: My bad. Try `key=...` instead of `on=...`. Flying blind here

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a dataframe to work with, so I proposed you the following dummy  dataframe :

```py
         Date  DTB6
0  2023-01-01   NaN
1  2023-01-02   NaN
2  2023-01-03  45.0
3  2023-01-04  96.0
4  2023-01-05   7.0
5  2023-01-06   NaN
6  2023-01-07   NaN
7  2023-01-08  45.0
8  2023-01-09  96.0
9  2023-01-10   7.0
10 2023-01-11   NaN
11 2023-01-12   NaN
12 2023-01-13  45.0
13 2023-01-14  96.0
14 2023-01-15   7.0
15 2023-01-16   NaN
16 2023-01-17   NaN
17 2023-01-18  45.0
18 2023-01-19  96.0
19 2023-01-20   7.0
20 2023-01-21   NaN
21 2023-01-22   NaN
22 2023-01-23  45.0
23 2023-01-24  96.0
24 2023-01-25   7.0
25 2023-01-26   NaN
26 2023-01-27   NaN
27 2023-01-28  45.0
28 2023-01-29  96.0
29 2023-01-30   7.0
30 2023-01-31   NaN
31 2023-02-01   NaN
32 2023-02-02  45.0
33 2023-02-03  96.0
34 2023-02-04   7.0
35 2023-02-05   NaN
36 2023-02-06   NaN
37 2023-02-07  45.0
38 2023-02-08  96.0
39 2023-02-09   7.0
```

Our target, if I understand well is to pick up the first non-na row by month.

**Proposed script**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023', end='2/09/2023'),
                   'DTB6': [np.nan, np.nan, 45, 96, 7]*8
                   })


r = (df.loc[df['DTB6'].notna()] # Filter out NaN rows
       .groupby(df.Date.dt.month) # Group by month
       .first() # Get first row
       .rename_axis(None, axis=0) # Delete index name
       )

print(r)
```

**Result**

```py
        Date  DTB6
1 2023-01-03  45.0
2 2023-02-02  45.0
```